# how to fix /usr/bin/install: missing destination file operand after '$HOME/toolchain/glibc-build/cstdlibT'

Tags: cygwin, glibc

I'm using cygwin building glibc-2.25. I've followed up to http://clfs.org/view/sysvinit/x86_64/cross-tools/glibc-64.html.

I've compiled

- File-5.31
- Linux-4.9.21 Headers
- M4-1.4.18
- Ncurses-6.0
- Pkg-config-lite-0.28-1
- GMP-6.1.2
- MPFR-3.1.5
- MPC-1.0.3
- ISL-0.17.1
- Cross Binutils-2.28
- Cross GCC-7.1.0 - Static

up to Glibc-2.25 64-Bit

Here's the configure script commands I'm using

```
BUILD_CC="gcc" CC="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -m64"  AR="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar"
RANLIB="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib" ../glibc-2.25/configure --prefix=/usr/local/cross-tools --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --libdir=/usr/local/cross-tools/lib64 --enable-kernel=3.12.0 --with-binutils=/usr/local/cross-tools/bin --with-headers=/usr/local/cross-tools/include --enable-obsolete-rpc --cache-file=config.cache
```